A trivial tensor product of an element and a projective module implies that the element is trivial?
Let $R$ be a ring and $M \neq 0$ and $N \neq 0$ a right and a left $R$-module, both finitely generated. Assume that $N$ is a projective module. If for some $m \in M$ it holds that
$$
0 = m \otimes_R n \in M \otimes_R N
$$
for all $n \in N$, then is it true that $m$ must necessarily be zero? I would most like a dual basis answer to this question.

What have you tried?

No, consider $N = 0$. Please clarify.

@azif00: I have taken a dual basis $n_i$ and $n^i$ and then acted on the element $m \otimes n_i$ by the map $\mathrm{id} \otimes n^j$ to get $mn^j(n_i)$. Now since we have a dual basis $n^j(n_i)$ must be non-zero for some $j$. Hence if there were no zero divisors in $N$ we would be able to conclude that $m$ is non-zero. But I would like not to assume that we have no zero divisors.

@Martin Brandenburg: I have added a non-zero assumption.

@FShrike: This is of course true - but I assume that $m \otimes_R n = 0$ for all $n \in N$ and in your example $1 \otimes 1$ is non-zero.

sorry, misread. The hypotheses imply that scalar multiplication $\mathrm{Ann}_R(m)\otimes_R N\to N$ is an isomorphism, and I'm not sure if you can wrangle anything from that in general but certain if $N$ is nonzero you get to conclude $m$ is torsion

Do you assume that $N$ is finitely generated? Your assumption $N \neq 0$ is certainly not enough, you really want that $N$ is nowhere zero, so in the commutative case that $N_{\mathfrak{p}} \neq 0$ for every prime $\mathfrak{p}$. Otherwise you cannot say anything about $m$ at $\mathfrak{p}$. Consider for example $R = R_1 \times R_2$ (product of two non-trivial rings). Then $R_1 \otimes_R R_2 = 0$ is a counterexample.

@Martin Brandenburg: I have added the assumption of finitely generated.

@FShrike: What is $Ann_R(m)$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)

As commented, the answer is no, because we have $R_1 \otimes_{R_1 \times R_2} R_2 = 0$.
But the following is true: Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and let $N$ be a finitely generated projective $R$-module such that $N_{\mathfrak{p}} \neq 0$ for all $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$. Then if $m \in M$ satisfies $m \otimes n = 0$ for all $n \in N$, then $m = 0$. In other words, the unit $\eta : M \to \hom(N,M \otimes N)$ is injective.
Proof: Since $N$ is finitely generated projective, $\hom(N,T)_{\mathfrak{p}} = \hom(N_{\mathfrak{p}},T_{\mathfrak{p}})$. Hence w.l.o.g. $R$ is local and thus $N$ is a free $R$-module of positive rank. Then $R$ is a direct summand of $N$, so that $M$ is a direct summand of $M \otimes N$, and the claim follows.

What is the action of $R_1 \times R_2$ on $R_1$ and on $R_2$?

The projections are ring homomorphisms, hence provide module structures. Concretely, $(r_1,r_2) \cdot x = r_1 x$ for $x \in R_1$. Notice $(1,0) x = x$ for the module structure on $R_1$ but $(0,1) x = x$ for the module structure on $R_2$, and $(1,0) (0,1) = 0$. This is why the tensor product vanishes.
